# ROS2 Launch - How to Concatenate LaunchConfiguration with String

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a preferred way to concatenate a `LaunchConfiguration` with a string (e.g. a file extension, prefix, or suffix) that can be used in a similar way to `PathJoinSubstitution`?

e.g. given:

```
DeclareLaunchArgument('my_robot', default_value='my_robot_name')
```

a path could be made to `my_robot` using:

```
PathJoinSubstitution(['path', 'to', LaunchConfiguration('my_robot')])
```

which would evaluate as:

```
/path/to/my_robot_name
```

But what if I want to create a path to `my_robot_name.config`? Is there an equivalent way to combine strings and `LaunchConfiguration`s?

As a workaround, I've used `Command` or `PythonExpression` substitutions, e.g.:

```
Command(['echo -n ', LaunchConfiguration('robot_name'), '.config'])  # or
PythonExpression(["'", LaunchConfiguration('robot_name'), ".config'"])
```

But I think it would be great if there was a cleaner, more readable alternative that I've completely overlooked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384712/ros2-launch---how-to-concatenate-launchconfiguration-with-string/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-08-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Fetullah Atas' answer got me most of the way there. Moving my comment to an answer to hopefully improve visibility. As a potential correction to his example, using a secondary launch argument that references the first is *one possible workaround*.

Example:

```
joy_config = LaunchConfiguration('joy_config')
joy_config_dec= DeclareLaunchArgument('joy_config', default_value='ps3')
final_string_dec= DeclareLaunchArgument('final_string', default_value=[LaunchConfiguration('joy_config'), '.config.yaml'])
```

Which would result in `LaunchConfiguration('final_string')` evaluating to: `"ps3.config.yaml"`.

I'd be surprised if there wasn't a more direct solution since this question was originally asked.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2023-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi for this particular case, `launch.substitutions.TextSubstitution` might be what you are looking for.

You can see see example usage of the case here;

```
 joy_config = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('joy_config')
 joy_config_dec= launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('joy_config', default_value='ps3'),

 final_string = os.path.join(joy_config, launch.substitutions.TextSubstitution(text='.config.yaml'))
```

The final string should be "`ps3.config.yaml`"

You can see complete example and reference at here ; https://github.com/ros2/teleop_twist_joy/tree/foxy/config

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2021-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-08-20**:
It seems the example you linked uses a list of strings and TextSubstitutions in the context of setting the default argument. Using substitutions directly within `os.path.join` will result in an error, as `join()` expects a string. In Foxy it results in:

```
Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not LaunchConfiguration
```

In any case, thank you! The method demonstrated in the linked example (creating a new launch argument with a default value based on a previous argument) is a better approach than what I was doing!

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-08-20**:
As a potential correction to your example, the following works as expected:

```
joy_config = LaunchConfiguration('joy_config')
joy_config_dec= DeclareLaunchArgument('joy_config', default_value='ps3')
final_string_dec= DeclareLaunchArgument('final_string', default_value=[LaunchConfiguration('joy_config'), '.config.yaml'])
```

Which would result in `LaunchConfiguration('final_string')` evaluating to: "`ps3.config.yaml`" without the explicit use of `TextSubstitution`. In fact, I am still unclear what `TextSubstitution`'s purpose is - perhaps it is a legacy function from before ROS2 was able to parse a mixed list of strings and LaunchConfigurations?

Answer (score 0):

@shonigman's answer to his own question does not work for me any longer in Humble. What does work is:

```
robot_name = DeclareLaunchArgument("robot_name", default_value="robot_0")

map_to_odom_tf_pub = Node(
    package="tf2_ros",
    executable="static_transform_publisher",
    arguments=["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "map", [LaunchConfiguration("robot_name"), "/odom"]],
    output="screen",
)
```

In other words, "/odom" is concatenated to the preexisting LaunchConfiguration like so:

```
    arguments=["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "map", [LaunchConfiguration("robot_name"), "/odom"]],
```